# How do I get number of results (rows) in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Normally the query below gives me only one result (row).

```
SELECT
    `s`.`FIRMA_UNVANI` AS `FIRMA_UNVANI`,
    `s`.`RECNO` AS `RECNO`,
    `s`.`BOLGE` AS `BOLGE`,
    `s`.`BOLGE_NO` AS `BOLGE_NO`,
    `s`.`DURUM` AS `DURUM`,
    l.ILCE,
    IL.SEHIR,
    count(i.recno) AS NUMBER_OF_WORKS
FROM
    `SERVISLER` `s`
LEFT JOIN KULLANICI k ON (s.BOLGE = k.KULLANICI)
LEFT JOIN kullanici_cihaz kc ON (k.RECNO = kc.KUL_RECNO)
LEFT JOIN servisler_ilceler c ON (s.RECNO = c.SER_RECNO)
INNER JOIN ILCE l ON (l.RECNO = c.ILCE_RECNO)
INNER JOIN IL ON (IL.ID = l.ILID)
LEFT JOIN ISEMRI i ON (
    i.bolge = s.bolge_no
    AND i.`SERVIS_DURUMU` = 1
)
WHERE
    1 = 1
GROUP BY
    s.BOLGE
ORDER BY
    IS_SAYISI
LIMIT 0,
 15
```

I get only one result

```
+----------------+-------+------+---------+------+-----+----------+-----------------+
|FIRMA_UNVANI    |RECNO  |BOLGE |BOLGE_NO |DURUM |ILCE | SEHIR    | NUMBER_OF_WORKS |
+----------------+-------+------+---------+------+-----+----------+-----------------+
|Pirana          |2501   |Tekkt |58       |-1    |NT   |Istanbul  |1428             |
+----------------+-------+------+---------+------+-----+----------+-----------------+
```

Here the key is RECNO.

I want to count the results:

```
SELECT
    count(0) AS _count
FROM
    `SERVISLER` `s`
LEFT JOIN KULLANICI k ON (s.BOLGE = k.KULLANICI)
LEFT JOIN kullanici_cihaz kc ON (k.RECNO = kc.KUL_RECNO)
LEFT JOIN servisler_ilceler c ON (s.RECNO = c.SER_RECNO)
INNER JOIN ILCE l ON (l.RECNO = c.ILCE_RECNO)
INNER JOIN IL ON (IL.ID = l.ILID)
LEFT JOIN ISEMRI i ON (
    i.bolge = s.bolge_no
    AND i.`SERVIS_DURUMU` = 1
)
WHERE
    1 = 1
GROUP BY
    s.BOLGE
```

And I get this wired result:

```
1428
```

It was supposed to be `1`. Isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result is perfectly fine, since you are just counting a 0 for every row instead of `i.recno`, therefore both resulting in 1428.

To count the number of results, you could wrap your whole query like this to get a `resultcount`:

```
SELECT count(*) AS resultcount FROM (
    SELECT
        `s`.`FIRMA_UNVANI` AS `FIRMA_UNVANI`,
        `s`.`RECNO` AS `RECNO`,
        `s`.`BOLGE` AS `BOLGE`,
        `s`.`BOLGE_NO` AS `BOLGE_NO`,
        `s`.`DURUM` AS `DURUM`,
        l.ILCE,
        IL.SEHIR,
        count(i.recno) AS NUMBER_OF_WORKS
    FROM
        `SERVISLER` `s`
    LEFT JOIN KULLANICI k ON (s.BOLGE = k.KULLANICI)
    LEFT JOIN kullanici_cihaz kc ON (k.RECNO = kc.KUL_RECNO)
    LEFT JOIN servisler_ilceler c ON (s.RECNO = c.SER_RECNO)
    INNER JOIN ILCE l ON (l.RECNO = c.ILCE_RECNO)
    INNER JOIN IL ON (IL.ID = l.ILID)
    LEFT JOIN ISEMRI i ON (
        i.bolge = s.bolge_no
        AND i.`SERVIS_DURUMU` = 1
    )
    GROUP BY
        s.BOLGE
    ORDER BY
        IS_SAYISI
    LIMIT 0, 15) AS temp
```

Also note, that `WHERE 1=1` is not necessary.

Comment: It only needs  `temp` at the very end.

Answer (score 2):

You have used `GROUP BY` in your query so you will get each group count in result, For example if there 3 group then you will get `3` count result..

If you need to get count of result rows then please use sub query see below

```
SELECT count(0) AS _count FROM(
  SELECT
     *
   FROM
    `SERVISLER` `s`
   LEFT JOIN KULLANICI k ON (s.BOLGE = k.KULLANICI)
   LEFT JOIN kullanici_cihaz kc ON (k.RECNO = kc.KUL_RECNO)
   LEFT JOIN servisler_ilceler c ON (s.RECNO = c.SER_RECNO)
   INNER JOIN ILCE l ON (l.RECNO = c.ILCE_RECNO)
   INNER JOIN IL ON (IL.ID = l.ILID)
   LEFT JOIN ISEMRI i ON (
    i.bolge = s.bolge_no
    AND i.`SERVIS_DURUMU` = 1
   )
   WHERE
    1 = 1
   GROUP BY
     s.BOLGE
) AS Temp;
```